# JavaFX TableView right click customizations

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, tableview

In Windows Explorer, we have this:

[image]

Do we have similar in JavaFX? I'm totally OK with implementing my own but just in case there in one already built in(or maybe some other libraries that does this).

I've searched for a while but there's not much on TableView.

Comment: You can add a column chooser using table.setMenuButtonVisible(true);

Comment: Do you want to move that to an answer? Because that solved it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a column chooser using `table.setMenuButtonVisible(true)`.  You can also style the button in css using `.table-view .show-hide-columns-button` and `.table-view .show-hide-column-image`.  They are both stack panes.